# Snowpark: Is it possible to configure a loop so the previous results (from prev. elements) aren't overwritten by the subsequent element in a list?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In an attempt to dynamically flatten a JSON (the JSON is in a column called 'SEMI_STRUCTUED_DATA'), I'm looping through a list (which has the same number of elements as the no. of rows in the dataframe.

```
my_list = ['flight_type','boat_type','helicopter_type']
```

Here's what I've written:

```
for x in my_list:
            k = dataframe.select(col("SEMI_STRUCTURED_DATA")[x])
    
    return k
```

The loop is working but not as expected. It's overwriting it each time. So the final result, is just the rows where 'helicopter_type' is what's required  to flatten it. Nulls for the others.

Is there way to correct- potentially by configuring the loop? Or, by appending the different results?

Answer (score 0):

```
It's because you overwrite k each time in the loop, and return only the last one. 
You should add k to a result list inside your for loop: result = result + k

So a proper aggregating loop structure is something like:

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val my_list = Seq("flight_type", "boat_type", "helicopter_type")
var resultDFs = List.empty[DataFrame]

for (x <- my_list) {
  val k = dataframe.select(col("SEMI_STRUCTURED_DATA")(x))
  resultDFs = resultDFs :+ k
}

val finalResult = resultDFs.reduce(_ union _)
```

If you would like to adapt your code, you should have something like

```
import pandas as pd
 
k = pd.DataFrame()
for x in my_list:
    k = k.append(dataframe.select(col("SEMI_STRUCTURED_DATA")[x]))
    # Using the append will not overwrite previous results
# After appending all of the results together, you can return it 
return k
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error- because of the curly brackets. Tried replacing it with every other kind but it still doesn't work. If I remove the brackets, then it errors at val k.

Comment: And also, I don't really understand this line: var resultDFs = List.empty[DataFrame]
What is going to be appended to the list?

Comment: This was just a pseudo code to illustrate the need to append the result to the previous results.

Adapting your code would look like:

import pandas as pd
 
k = pd.DataFrame()
for x in my_list:
    k = k.append(dataframe.select(col("SEMI_STRUCTURED_DATA")[x]))
    # Using the append will not overwrite previous results
# After appending all of the results together, you can return it 
return k

Comment: Getting this errror: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. I know understand what you're doing but unsure about how to write the exact code. The part after append looks more like spark code. Not sure how to write it fully in Pandas. I will then convert it back to snowpark after. So I can return a Snowpark table.